Replace single pole switch with 3 black wires
I am trying to replace a single pole light switch that controls a bedroom light/fan combo. Switch only controls lights, fan operated by pull chain.
The old switch is using 3 black wires. All other white and ground wires pigtailed together in box.
I determined that one of the black wires on bottom of switch is the line using a voltage tester. I assume the other black wire next to it is the load to the outlets in room.
The new Kasa KS200 smart switch has 2 black wires (line/load) a white wire (neutral) and the green (ground wire).
Do I wire up the line/load wires to the 2 black wires on the Kasa switch, and the 3rd black wire from old switch to the white wire on the new kasa switch?
Any advice appreciated



No.
You pigtail the two(really a single) black wires to line on the new switch. Cut the two apart and use a wire nut of the right size and connect to line of the switch.
The single black on top is the switched hot and goes to load.
The neutral goes to the neutrals in the back of the box.  And ground to the grounds.
Make sure the breaker is off.

Breaker off. Voltage tester confirms this.
If I understood correctly. I take the 2 black wires off the bottom of old switch and put them both together with the Black line wire on new switch, and the single black wire to the load wire on new switch. The white wire and ground wire get pigtailed to the wires in the box?  The new switch doesn’t indicate which black wire is the line or load. Does it matter which one I use for the line? Thanks for the advice

@Headlie   I know simple switches it does not matter, it seems it does not matter for that switch either, but check the instructions.

Thanks. New switch is working and connected to WiFi.

Followed crip659’s advice. New smart switch working now.
Connected the 2 black wires together to the live black wire on new switch, and the single black wire to the load wire on new switch. Connected the white and ground wires to corresponding wires in the box.
On the KS200 smart switch, there is no difference between the line and load wires, you can use either wire.
Thanks for the help.
